# Traversing a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, optimization

The data which I fetch from PHP page is like:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": null,
    "startdate": "2012-07-20",
    "starttime": "09:53:02",
    "enddate": "2012-07-20",
    "endtime": "09:54:10",
    "duration": "01:00:00",
    "feedbacks": [{
        "id": "1",
        "type": "1",
        "content": "cont"
    }],
    "conditions": [{
        "id": "1",
        "dev_id": "1",
        "mod_id": "2",
        "sub_id": "3",
        "to_be_compared_value": "1",
        "comparison_type": "1"
    }],
    "actions": [{
        "id": "1",
        "dev_id": "1",
        "mod_id": "1",
        "sub_id": "1",
        "target_action": "1"
    }]
}]
```

Which way is easy, efficent and elegant to traverse this object? I used this two until this time. Can you tell me which one must be my choice, or can you give me an alternative? And why? I have a running version of my application and I'm reviewing now my own code, and I want to take some advices from you all.

Thanks in advance,

Methods I use before:

```
$.map
for(var i in obj)
```

**One more to go, I will create a table from this data.**

Comment: couldn't JSON.parse() be used?

Comment: Yes, after parsing it, I have an object, which way I can efficiently use this object?

Comment: Depends on what way you want to use it? Looping over it or mapping a function over it are both perfectly good actions to perform in the right context. But what exactly do you want to do with this data?

Comment: What is meant by efficiently use this object?

Comment: Sure, I will tell: I use this object with all of its data, therefore I have to traverse all object with a way, I'm just not sure which way I can follow is best?

Comment: var i in obj will traverse all object properties, so you are going to have to check each time with "hasownproperty". $.map adds the overhead of using jQuery. The way to go if you are looking for efficiency is to parse the string into an object and use array keys for whatever data you need to alter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [jQuery's each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) (or [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) if I wanted to change the data)

I should add that you should also create a function which returns an object (possibly even with some utility methods), since your data isn't very JS-friendly right now. Those dates and times, those ID's as strings.

Example:

```
    function cleanMyObject(object){
        var cleanFeedbacks = function(feedbacks){
            /* ... */
            return feedback;
        };

        object.start = /* transform date and time strings to datetime object ...*/
        object.end = /*...*/

        /*...*/

        $.map(object.feedbacks,cleanFeedbacks);
        /* cleanup the remaining objects... */

        return object;
    }

    $.map(receivedData, cleanMyObject);

    // cleanMyObject() returns the modified object so $.map will clean everything in your array.
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use http://underscorejs.org/ for things like this. It has a lot of useful functions for objects, collections etc.

Comment: I love that! Where was she all this time :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data you are recieving doesn't change, just parse the object and use the keys you need. 
All browsers I'm aware of have a function called [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON/) to convert a JSON string into a JS object.
What I'm trying to say is: Don't be lazy, you aren't gaining any benefits from writing a "general" function if your object will always provide the same data, and there is little to no chance you can use that function again with a different object.

```
var myobj= JSON.parse(phpJSONstring);
var feedbacks= myobj["feedbacks"];
//do something with feedbacks
var conditions= myobj["conditions"];
//do something with conditions
```

etc

Comment: There will not be just one record of this data there, will a lot, a thusand and may be bigger than that.

Comment: just use JSON.parse on each one and you should be fine. I doubt there is a more efficient way

Comment: Ok, **I know to use JSON parse**

Answer (score -1):

You can transform the json string in a javascript object, and then access the object like this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
alert('Id='+obj.id);

var feedbackList = obj.feedbacks;
for (var i=0; i<feedbackList.length; i++) {
   ...
}
```

Reference to jQuery.parseJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I stated in comment that I'm already transform this object. But thank you for your opinion.